# Python: ignore multiple returns

Tags: python-3.x

I see in others questions that one safe way to ignore return values is to use the double underscore `__`, so for example:

```
def f()
    return 1, 2

a, __ = f()
```

In my case, I always need the first output and sometime the second. Is there a way to avoid the double underscore solution, so to have

```
a = f()
```

or

```
a, b = f()
```

I was thinking about a flag, like

```
def f(full_output=False)
    if full_output:
        return 1, 2
    else:
        return 1
```

but I was wondering if there is a more "elegant" solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is more a matter of style, you could just use `f()[0]` instead of unpacking the result. I've never seen the recommdation to use a *double* underscore, conventionally a single one is used.